# Share logic between queries in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing a web app, and I might have logic such as "When Field A = value and Field B = other value, then this should be shown in the frontend." I might have different lists, which further elaborate on this. I might even have translated entities which have the translation in a different entity (example: Entity and EntityTranslation) and want to join them only on a specific locale.

How could I reuse all this logic, to avoid repeating the same `QueryBuilder::andWhere()` and `QueryBuilder::join()` (even `QueryBuilder::select()`) calls all over the place?

I've found http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/03/04/doctrine_repositories.html which talks on this, but I'm curious about solutions which involve also JOINs and SELECT.

EDIT:

Bad example of what I'd want:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->andWhere(FRONTEND_LOGIC)
    ->joinWithTranslationTable();
```

So I'd want to be able to compose "complex" queries from my, simpler, but Buisiness driven, parts.

Comment: Not understanding your question.  I'm assuming you are using the query builder object?  If you have a common set of (for example) join statements then just move this statements to their own method and pass the query builder as an argument.  But I suspect you are asking something else.  Perhaps you can update the question with an example?

Comment: I've tried to clarify it a bit. In short, I want to avoid having the same andWhere(), select(), join() calls everywhere in my queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared statements in Doctrine's DBAL layer.

```
   $dbal = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('default');
   $stmt = 'SELECT name, birth from user where id = :id';

   $user1 = $dbal->executeQuery( $stmt , array( 'id' => 1 ) )->fetchAll() ;
   $user2 = $dbal->executeQuery( $stmt , array( 'id' => 2 ) )->fetchAll() ;
```

Refer to the documentation for other methods suitable for your task:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.0.x/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements

Comment: That's not what I meant. Prepared statements are a whole query, I'm talking about re-use of parts of a query. Also, when linking to the docs, try to link to current :)

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine does not allow you to specify the query builder class so you cannot directly extend it.  You can however decorate it.

```
class MyQueryBuilder
{
    public function __construct($doctrineQueryBuilder) { this->doctrineQueryBuilder = $doctrineQueryBuilder; }

    // Your custom functions
    public function addWhereFrontEndLogic ...
    public function joinWithTranslationTable ...

   // Also need to add the the regular methods that you use
   public function addSelect($value) { return $this->doctrineQueryBuilder($value); }

// You would then
$qb = new MyQueryBuilder($this->createQueryBuilder());
```

Bit of a pain to have to add all the standard functions but once you have done it then you can add as much custom business logic as you want.

There are some other possible approaches.  You could add the custom methods to a base repository class and then just call the methods with the doctrine $qb as an argument.